# Automatically "comment out" formula in Excel?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, vba

So I have this result set in MS SQL Management Studio. And I have an Excel sheet. I copy and paste data from MSSMS to Excel. As far as good.

Now, some of the fields start with an equals sign. Excel thinks it is a formula and tries to evaluate it - which fails, because it is not a formula.

Now, I could manually insert a `'` in front of each of these. But they are very many, and I don't feel like it.

Is there a way to automatically treat pasted data as text, i.e. do not treat pasted data that starts with an equals sign as formula? I'm not opposed to VBA.

Google could unfortunately not help me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using macro:

1.Open your spreadsheet and hit the ‘Alt + F11’ keys to open the VBA editor.

2.Paste the below macro in the editor.

```
Sub FindFormulaCells()
     For Each cl In ActiveSheet.UsedRange
        If cl.HasFormula() = True Then
           cl.Value = "'" & cl.Value & "'"
        End If
     Next cl
End Sub
```

3.For running this formula press “F5” key.

Comment: Great! Should have thought about this myself...